# How can I save a datetime data from an input in a table

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a website in **php** with the **laravel framework** and I have a **database in phpmyadmin**, I have a form and 2 inputs of type datetime-local, when I select the datetime from the inputs and then I send the form I get this error.

[image]

The datetime data that I would like to insert into my Table of my database in that's error, it's:

**26, 2018-10-11T05:00, 2018-10-12T05:00.** That's letter **'T'** I think it's was me bring problems. **Is possible to change that letter to a blank space?** Possibly using javascript, o before the function `store()` of my Controller save the record in my database, can do something to save the datetime data from the inputs.

I put the code of the function `store()`

```
public function store(Request $request){


  $hours = new HoursNew();

  try {

    /*HERE ARE THE NAMES FROM THE INPUTS IN MY FORM, 
    ALSO THE NAMES OF THE FIELDS OF MY TABLE IN MY DATABASE*/ 

    $hours->id = $request->id;
    $hours->time_start = $request->time_start;
    $hours->time_end = $request->time_end;
    $hours->estate_time_id = $request->estate_time_id;
    $hours->court_id = $request->court_id;
    $hours->save();


    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

        Session::flash('error', 'Ups! We have some problems to process your operation');

        return redirect()->route('ListHours.store');
    }
        Session::flash('message', "It's OK");
        return redirect()->route('ListHours.store');
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to use the DateTime class in PHP to convert that date to a format that the database can deal with like `Y-m-d H:i:s` Start by [looking at this in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: You have to change the dateFormat

Comment: can you share migration accodding to the above model?

Comment: you have another error in your cancha_id too; maybe your datetime is correct; check the id; you have a extra space before your number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the Request fields that dont conform to the database datetime requirements you will have to reformat then like this for example

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\Th:i', $request->time_start);

$hours->time_start = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Now the website show me the following error: `Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ' 8' for column 'court_id' at row 1`

Comment: I would guess that column `court_id` should not have a date in it

Comment: What did you change

Comment: My mistake, in the form I put `&nbsp;` in this line: `<input value="&nbsp;{{$courts->id}}" >` I remove the `&nbsp` and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to format the date-time

example

**edited**

```
$hours->time_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->time_start));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my question, I have applied that code, but It not work, it show me the following error.                                                                           `A non well formed numeric value encountered`

Comment: @RiggsFolly may be you have put `26, 2018-10-11T05:00` to the `strtotime()`. but note that those are two values. `26` is the `id` and `2018-10-11T05:00` is the `time_start`

Comment: My mistake the `26` was not actually part of the date field it was the `id`

Answer (score 0):

You could use php DateTime's format function to put it into the correct format:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Laravel also has Carbon in it by default: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

I normally use Y-m-d H:i:s for my format string, but both of the docs show additional formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the date before calling save() function like this -

```
$hora_inicio = new DateTime($request->hora_inicio);

$hora_inicio = $hora_inicio->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');

$hora_fin = new DateTime($hora_fin);

$hora_fin = $hora_inicio->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

and then assign these variables to your object.

Comment: Without add the following line at the top of my code? this: `use DateTime;`

Comment: Yes, you have to use  this   use DateTime;   at the top